# Prevent default click event (WinAPI)

Tags: c++, c, winapi, gdi

I'm making a color dropper tool and while this tool is active, when the user clicks or taps I only want it to run my mouse event, not anything else,so while this tool is running,if the user clicks the start orb, it should not open the start menu (or if the user clicks anything else). How could I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a system-wide mouse event hook. Hooks are described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589(VS.85).aspx). Depending on your hook's return value, the application underneath the cursor will or will not receive the mouse event. You may need to implement a *low level* mouse hook in order to catch mouse clicks. The hook function should also be provided with the screen coordinates of the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Try `SetCapture()` / `ReleaseCapture()`.

Comment: Much cleaner than a hook. See also http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/127813/Using-SetCapture-and-ReleaseCapture-correctly-usua

Answer (score 0):

Create a screen-sized transparent window that you put on top of all other windows.